# How can I disable ButtonType.OK in a DialogPane?

Tags: javafx

How do you disable the OK button until certain conditions are met?

Here im itializing my DialogPane with  OK and CANCEL buttons.

```
    Dialog<ButtonType> testDialog = new Dialog<>();
    testDialog.initOwner(mainBorderPane.getScene().getWindow());
    testDialog.setTitle("Test Dialog");
    testDialog.setHeaderText(null);
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("testDialog.fxml"));
    try{
        testDialog.getDialogPane().setContent(fxmlLoader.load());
    } catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Couldn't load the dialog");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }`
    testDialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
    testDialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.CANCEL);
    Optional<ButtonType> result = testDialog.showAndWait();
```

Then I am trying to bind the conditions to the OK button.
Conditions being: TextField inputs must match time format (0-7hours, 0-59minuts)

```
@FXML
private TextField hoursField;
@FXML
private TextField minutesField;

public void initialize(){

    testDialogPane.lookupButton(ButtonType.OK).disableProperty()
            .bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
                    () -> !hoursField.getText().matches("[0-7]") ||
                            !minutesField.getText().matches("^[0-5]?[0-9]$"),
                    hoursField.textProperty(),
                    minutesField.textProperty()
            ));
}
```

Ofc, I'm getting a java.lang.NullPointerException because buttons or not existing at the initialize runtime.
Is there any other way around?

Comment: Those `TextField`s are part  of the `Dialog` or they are separate in Controller?

Comment: They are part of DialogController not from the main window controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the binding after you add the `OK` button to the dialog.

You have to add a getter for each `TextField` in the controller, then after you 
load the `testDialog.fxml` you can assign the its controller to a reference like: `DialogController controller = fxmlLoader.getController();` (swap DialogController with your controller)

Then after `testDialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);`

do the binding:

```
testDialogPane.lookupButton(ButtonType.OK).disableProperty()
            .bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
                    () -> !controller.getHoursField.getText().matches("[0-7]") ||
                            !controller.getMinutesField.getText().matches("^[0-5]?[0-9]$"),
                    controller.getHoursField.textProperty(),
                    controller.getMinutesField.textProperty()
            ));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was kinda desperate after 2 days of searching alternative solutions... Got it working now thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your controller class that returns a `BooleanExpression` for valid/invalid input.

#### Controller

```
private BooleanExpression invalidInput;

public BooleanExpression invalidInputProperty() {
    if (invalidInput == null) {
        invalidInput = Bindings.createBooleanBinding(
                                        () -> !hoursField.getText().matches("[0-7]") ||
                                              !minutesField.getText().matches("^[0-5]?[0-9]$"),
                                        hoursField.textProperty(),
                                        minutesField.textProperty()
                                );
    }
    return invalidInput;
}
```

#### Dialog creation:

```
fxmlLoader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("testDialog.fxml"));
testDialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.OK, ButtonType.CANCEL);
try{
    testDialog.getDialogPane().setContent(fxmlLoader.load());
    Controller controller = fxmlLoader.getController(); // depending on the name of the controller class you may need to adjust this
    testDialog.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK)
                              .disableProperty()
                              .bind(controller.invalidInputProperty());
} catch(IOException e){
    System.out.println("Couldn't load the dialog");
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I might implement your solution since i will have to reuse this binding on some other Dialogs.

Comment: Do you think it could be possible to use a try(LocalTime.parse input){} catch{} in that invalidInputProperty method? So i could disable a button until a correct time format is entered ?